# how to increase combox box size in html page

Tags: javascript, html

I want to create combobox and i want to increase the size but it does not increase so how to increase size in html file.

```
 <html>
 <SELECT NAME="food" SIZE=10> 
 <OPTION VALUE="0">OK 
 <OPTION VALUE="1">Good 
 <OPTION VALUE="2">Best 
 <OPTION VALUE="3">Average 
 </SELECT> 
 </html>
```

Comment: What do you mean? You need to have at least as many entries as the size you set.

Comment: On an iDevice you will get one row regardless of the size parm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean you want to increase the width of the combo box?

```
<SELECT NAME="food" SIZE="10" style="width: 200px;">
```

Comment: how to change the height of the combo box

Comment: If you're having trouble with size, you can use style="height: 200px;"